# Does the edge of the shadow of a person's head move in a straight line if the person moves in a straight line with the light source fixed in a place?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

So, let's say that there is a light source at a height "H" above the ground. A person of height "x" starts moving in a straight line with uniform velocity (not direct under the source of light) and passes the light source at a point. Now what I am dubious about is that, if the edge of the shadow of the person's head also move in a straight line during the motion too? I was initially presuming that it would, but then when I tried applying the Pythagorean theorem for the triangle (formed by connecting the edge of the shadow of the head to the source, the line connecting edge of the shadow to the wall of the source, and the source with the wall), it seems like the distance between the edge of the shadow from the source of light is different at each point. I really am not sure even though it seems like I vouch for the latter (not being in the straight line), but I wish to know and look forward to understand what really it is.

Comment: Are we assuming a point-head that makes a point-shadow, or an actual sphere-ish head with positive radius? And if so, which part of the edge of the shadow are you following?

Comment: I guess any point works as long as we keep tracking the same one until the motion is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the shadow of the top of the walker's head falls on the same level ground on which he is walking.

Suppose the light source is at $L$ vertically above point $O$ on the ground and $N$ is the point on the walker's path closest to $O$, where $ON=d$. At some time $t$ the walker of height $x$ has moved to a point $P$ so that the top of his head, point $X$, makes a shadow at point $Q$ on the ground.

Let the perpendicular distance from $Q$ to the path be $y$, and let $\angle NOP=\theta$. Then we have

$OP=d\csc\theta$ and $PQ=y\csc\theta$.

Then by similar triangles, $$\frac{H}{x}=\frac{(d+y)\csc \theta}{y\csc\theta}=\frac{d+y}{y}$$

Rearranging, $$y=\frac{xd}{H+x}$$

This indicates that $y$ remains constant and the path of the shadow is therefore a straight line parallel to the walker's. The walker doesn't have to move at constant speed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer David, appreciate it. It's clear to me now that it doesn't depend on the $\theta$ and the point stays on the line. But can you also clarify about the case where the person walks collinearly, i.e according to the notations used by you "ON=0?". I would like to know what would happen in that case.

Comment: You're welcome. In the case when $d=0$ then the points $L,O,P,X$ and $Q$ remain in the same vertical plane, so the tip of the shadow, $Q$ remains on the same straight line on which the walker is walking. This is consistent with the general result I gave in my answer, i.e. $d=0\implies y=0$

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you again, David.